# javac flag to print only the error locations

Tags: javac, verbosity

Is it possible to make `javac` output only the error locations and the error messages, and hide the source code dump?

Now I get:

```
$ javac t.java
t.java:1: <identifier> expected
class {
     ^
t.java:2: reached end of file while parsing
bar
   ^
t.java:4: reached end of file while parsing

^
3 errors
```

I want to get only:

```
$ javac ... t.java
t.java:1: <identifier> expected
t.java:2: reached end of file while parsing
t.java:4: reached end of file while parsing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no flag you could pass to javac, but you can simply filter the output through any program which removes the superfluous lines. Here an example with grep:

```
javac t.java 2>&1 | egrep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_/]+\.java:[0-9]+: '
```

You might have to change the part matching the file name if you have strange letters in your file name - this seems to work for the ASCII subset.

Comment: Your pipe solution doesn't work without `2>&1` in front of `|`. I'm already writing my script to parse the output of javac properly, I just wanted to avoid that work.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks for noting this. (I did not really try it with a real javac but with `cat javac-output | ...` instead.)